# Cannot execute Laravel Artisan commands on shared hosting

Tags: php, shell, laravel, hosting, bluehost

I uploaded laravel app to shared hosting into a domain folder, and made .htaccess so that it redirects requests to laravel's /public folder.
I now want to execute artisan commands through ssh. I tried just typing `php artisan list` in laravel's root folder on the shared host, but it gives me this output (it prints it in html, but I just copied the exeption for readability):

```
ErrorException thrown with message "Undefined index: argv"

Stacktrace:
#3 ErrorException in /home5/petophob/public_html/ees-aleksandarnikolic/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php:57
#2 Illuminate\Exception\Handler:handleError in /home5/petophob/public_html/ees-aleksandarnikolic/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php:57
#1 Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput:__construct in /home5/petophob/public_html/ees-aleksandarnikolic/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:114
#0 Symfony\Component\Console\Application:run in /home5/petophob/public_html/ees-aleksandarnikolic/artisan:58
```

What can I do to make it work? I'm on Bluehost, if that's relevant.

Thanks,

Petar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try call it: `php-cli artisan list`

If it will not be working you should probably contact bluehost support it is about server settings.

Answer (score 0):

if artisan commands are not working inside your server, you can execute the PHP scripts via PHP's command-line interface (CLI). inside a server, the server pilot installs various versions of the PHP version. to determine what version of PHP you are using, you can simply render a `php_info()` page.

to execute artisan command you can run CLI base commands based on your version. if you use php version `7.3` you can use

`php7.3-cli artisan list`

`php7.3-cli artisan migrate`

`php7.3-cli artisan db:seed`

PHP syntax will be changed based on your current version what you have to do is just change the version of your command `phpVERSION-cli` example `php8.0-cli`